# How to let a data class implements Interface / extends Superclass properties in Kotlin?

Tags: inheritance, properties, kotlin, data-class

I have several data classes which include a `var id: Int?` field. I want to express this in an *interface* or *superclass*, and have data classes extending that and setting this `id` when they are constructed. However, if I try this:

```
interface B {
  var id: Int?
}

data class A(var id: Int) : B(id)
```

It complains I'm overriding the `id` field, which I am haha..

**Q**: How can I let the data class `A` in this case to take an `id` when it's constructed, and set that `id` declared in the *interface* or *superclass*?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Indeed, you needn't an [abstract class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#abstract-classes) yet. you can just override the [interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html#interfaces) properties, for example:

```
interface B {
    val id: Int?
}

//           v--- override the interface property by `override` keyword
data class A(override var id: Int) : B
```

An [interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html#interfaces) has no constructors so you can't call the constructor by `super(..)` keyword , but you can using an [abstract class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#abstract-classes) instead. Howerver, a [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) can't declare any parameters on its [primary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors), so it will **overwritten** the **field** of the superclass, for example:

```
//               v--- makes it can be override with `open` keyword
abstract class B(open val id: Int?)

//           v--- override the super property by `override` keyword
data class A(override var id: Int) : B(id) 
//                                   ^
// the field `id` in the class B is never used by A

// pass the parameter `id` to the super constructor
//                            v
class NormalClass(id: Int): B(id)
```

Comment: @EdyBourne Not at all. In fact, I'm confused by **superclass** word  in the question and  abuse **abstract class** at the first  time. I realized it has some troubles to let a `data class` extends a `class` until I wrote down the answer.  so I change my head and finally found that you just want to **implements** the interface *getters/setters* only.

Comment: `open val` - is that right? Seems like `protected final`

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar Hi, there is no problem. Since it assert that its getter can be override and its back-field also is **final**.

Comment: So it translates to a `private final` field with `protected` getter?

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar yeah, but the visibilitybis not changed getter is public.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface B {
    var id: Int?
}

data class A(override var id: Int?) : B

var a1:A = A(1)
var a2:A = A(null)
```